# async coroutine with volley

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to convert my pet app to use coroutines instead of callbacks.
I am half way, but I cannot see how to get around the callback I have in this function. Is there a way to use async to get rid of callbacks or am I climbing the wrong tree?

This is what I have so far:

```
const val url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"

class PokeClient {
    fun getPokemonData(context: Context, successCallBack: (Pokemon) -> Unit, pokemonName: String) = runBlocking {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val request = url.plus(pokemonName)

    var deferredResult = async {
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, request, Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            val jObj = JSONObject(response)
            val imgUrl = jObj
                .getJSONObject("sprites")
                .getJSONObject("other")
                .getJSONObject("official-artwork")
                .getString("front_default")

            val inputStream = URL(imgUrl).openStream()
            successCallBack(Pokemon(name = jObj.getString("name"), image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)))
        }, Response.ErrorListener {
            val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "error talking to professor Oak!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            toast.show()
        })

        queue.add(stringRequest)
        }

        deferredResult.await()
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Android Newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you need to convert network call with callback code block into a suspending function which can be called from any coroutine, this can be done using [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) function, it basically provides you with a continuation object, which can be used to return data from inside the Response callbacks in your case

```
suspend fun getPokemon() = suspendCoroutine<Pokemon> { cont ->
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"

    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<Pokemon> { response ->   
            val jObj = JSONObject(response)
            val imgUrl = jObj.getJSONObject("sprites")
                .getJSONObject("other")
                .getJSONObject("official-artwork")
                .getString("front_default")

            val inputStream = URL(imgUrl).openStream()
            /* call continuation.resume and pass your object */
            cont.resume(Pokemon(name = jObj.getString("name"), image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)))      
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { 
            /* if network call fails then post appropriate error */
            cont.resumeWithException(YourExceptoin) 
        })
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

Now you can call this `function` from a coroutine and get a `Pokemon` as following

```
runBlocking{
  try { val pokeMon = getPokemon() }
  catch(e: Exception) { Log.d(TAG, "Cant get pokemon") }
}
```

Note : its OK to use `runBlocking` only for learning and exploration otherwise its not a good idea, use `launch` or `async`

Edit : As noted in comment you can also use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` if you need to support cancellation (which you should for structured concurrency).

Comment: With `suspendCancellableCoroutine` you could also support cancellation, so the request doesn't unnecessarily continue if the coroutine is cancelled.

Comment: @mightyWOZ Thank you for the quality response. My code looks much better. 
However, you say not to use runBlocking. How can I avoid this in my synchronous MainActivity.kt? Which currently calls this getPokemon() function.

Comment: I learned elsewhere that runBlocking acts as a bridge, but it has to happen somewhere? am I wrong?

Comment: For now you can use GlobalScope.launch

Comment: I almost feel like onCreate() where I call it, should be a suspectCoroutine or something similar

Comment: **unlearn the bridge thing as fast as you can**, remember only one thing, _runBlocking should never be used in production code_ , it defeats the whole purpose of coroutines, because it blocks the calling thread

Comment: [Don't use GlobalScope either.](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) Use `lifecycleScope.launch`. But it would be better to do it inside a ViewModel and use `viewModelScope.launch` so your request doesn't have to restart every time the screen rotates. The coroutine can call your suspend function and place the result in a LiveData or SharedFlow for the Activity to observe.

Comment: `runBlocking` is the bridge in a native JVM app where the entry point is the `main` function. That's the one place it should ever be used outside of tests, and is irrelevant to Android apps or other UI-based apps like Swing or JavaFX which have their own coroutine scopes provided.